# React JS npm start shows failed to compile web-vitals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-start, web-vitals

I'm getting the error:

> failed to compile  -/src/reportWebVitals.js Module not found: Can't
> resolve 'web-vitals'. Since new to react JS, could not find what
> happened. Here is the reportWebVitals.JS file. Thanks in advance for
> the help.  "/src/reportWebVitals.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> 'web-vitals' in 'E:\ReactResources\RectProjects\test-app\src'"

```
const reportWebVitals = onPerfEntry => {
if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
import('web-vitals').then(({ getCLS, getFID, getFCP, getLCP, getTTFB }) => {
  getCLS(onPerfEntry);
  getFID(onPerfEntry);
  getFCP(onPerfEntry);
  getLCP(onPerfEntry);
  getTTFB(onPerfEntry);
});
}};
export default reportWebVitals;
```

Comment: _Can't resolve 'web-vitals'_ : Seems like you should install `web-vitals` using `npm i web-vitals`.

Comment: Resolved after deleting & re-installing all packages. May be there was missing packages  due to slow internet. Thanks Ajeet Shah.

Answer (score 83):

You need to install web vitals. Open your terminal and run the following command:

```
npm i web-vitals --save-dev
```

Also, deleting the whole thing and reinstalling might work, but that's a longer process.

Comment: For those using **yarn**: `yarn add -D web-vitals`

Comment: Interesting, create-react-app gives an issue, but installing web-vital again sorts the problem.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone coming here from starting a brand new app with `create-react-app`: If you are using `npm` but run `create-react-app` without explicitly specifying it, it will  use `yarn` when available.
I was able to bypass this issue by adding the flag `--use-npm`.

So, for example:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm
```

[Source](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#selecting-a-package-manager)

Answer (score 3):

for me following worked 
first do `npm uninstall react-scripts`
then do `npm install react-scripts`

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the files & Folders inside test-app folder. Reinstall all the packages now and start npm. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your project with `create-react-app`, all the dependencies should be there when you run `npm install`.

Make sure you did that by navigating to the root directory and running:

```
npm install
```

Comment: I did it and it did not work, you have to use npm install web-vitals.

Answer (score -2):

I closed my terminal and opened again. Works for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, this is not correct, web vitals fails due to a wrong package check, which implies that closing the terminal will not sort the issue.