# when using create-react-app dependencies @testing-library could not resolve

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, react-dom, testing-library

```
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: learn@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

When I used `npm start` it gives this error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/reportWebVitals.js 5:4-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-vitals' in 'D:\React\Education\Fetch api\my-learn\src'
```

I tried with clear cache,

deleting node modules and then again installing them (`npm install`),

Then changed from package.json to this:

change "react": "^18.0.0" & "react-dom": "^18.0.0" to an earlier version e.g. "react": "^17.0.2" & "react-dom": "^17.0.2".

Finally, run `npm install`.

None of the solutions worked for me. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From

[React JS npm start shows failed to compile web-vitals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396568/react-js-npm-start-shows-failed-to-compile-web-vitals)

Basically run

```
npm i web-vitals --save-dev
```

on your terminal and it should work.

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out, As i didn't needed the report-web-vital.js file i removed it from my project. Then it worked form me. If you dont need that file, i suggest you to remove that file and try running npm start again.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update `@testing-library/react` to the latest version to use it properly with React 18.
Run the command:

```sh
npm i @testing-library/react@13.0.1
```

Tested on my project where I had the same problem